# Why i have an ip for ssh and ifconfig shows another one in eth0?

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, ssh, ip

OS:  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1009-raspi2 armv7l)

So when i connect to my machine through ssh from windows with putty, i am able to do it with the IP **192.168.0.60**.

Now when im listing my devices from the router admin web, it shows that its using the IP **192.168.0.109**.

This is the output for the ifconfig cmd.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:86:e1:e0
      inet addr:192.168.0.109  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe86:e1e0/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2233 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1067 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:163132 (163.1 KB)  TX bytes:167801 (167.8 KB)
```

And this is what i have in ***etc/network/interfaces***

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.60
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
dns-nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Another fact to think about is that when i restart the networking service, it throws the following error:

```
    Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with
 error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This is the ***systemctl status networking.service*** output:

```
networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-03-23 15:31:59 UTC; 2min 1s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 2046 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2038 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list
 Main PID: 2046 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 23 15:31:58 ubuntu dhclient[2065]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.109 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6fc3c068)
Mar 23 15:31:58 ubuntu dhclient[2065]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.109 from 192.168.0.1
Mar 23 15:31:58 ubuntu ifup[2046]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Mar 23 15:31:59 ubuntu ifup[2046]: bound to 192.168.0.109 -- renewal in 657200529 seconds.
Mar 23 15:31:59 ubuntu ifup[2046]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Mar 23 15:31:59 ubuntu ifup[2046]: Failed to bring up eth0.
Mar 23 15:31:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 23 15:31:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Mar 23 15:31:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 23 15:31:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Notice the following line:

```
Mar 23 15:31:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

Can somebody tell me what is going on and how i could fix that?

**Edit:** Results of route -n:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: check if you have configured it with DHCP and also specified an static address in the cfg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potentially you had a static IP address defined but also had DHCP running.

Instead of using ifconfig, see if there are multiple ip addresses configured on the interface via

```
ip addr show eth0
```

See if there is a dhcp service running

```
ps -ef | grep dhcp
```

You can disable the dhcp service via

```
sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd
```

Then i would say restart the device and see if the secondary IP address has disappeared.
This could have happened because your DNS (/etc/resolv.conf) is setup correctly and points to your DHCP server to grab an IP

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you're making use of the */etc/network/interfaces* file within Ubuntu that it's best to disable Ubuntu's **NetworkManager**. My colleagues and I have experience weird issues when you've set static IPs and such in the config file but then NetworkManager likes to do its own thing.

Check out the [Stopping and Disabling NetworkManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager#Stopping_and_Disabling_NetworkManager) on the Ubuntu help site.

Though since you can access the Static IP even though your interface is receiving a dynamic one, it would be interesting to see what your routing table is like:  *route -n*

Comment: I edited the ask and added the output of route -n

Comment: So i disabled the network manager as the post says and im still getting the same error when restarting the networking service

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue.

- While logging in I could `ssh` from 192.168.1.83 and 192.168.1.253.
- But while configuring it, I made it manual IPv4 configuration and removed DHCP.
- But for some reason it took DHCP IP 192.168.1.83.
- I ran `ifconfig` and it showed the below output.

  ```
  [root@network ~]# ifconfig
  enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
  inet 192.168.1.83  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  ether 08:00:27:7c:23:31  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
  RX packets 11722  bytes 15567876 (14.8 MiB)
  RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
  TX packets 4551  bytes 331004 (323.2 KiB)
  TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
  ```
- If I execute `ip addr show` I get below output and I am confused why it is picking up two IPs. I remember removing 192.168.1.83 while configuring, but still it is showing up.

  ```
  [root@network ~]# ip addr show
  1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
      link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
      inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 ::1/128 scope host
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 08:00:27:7c:23:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.1.83/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
         valid_lft 85901sec preferred_lft 85901sec
      inet 192.168.1.253/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute enp0s3
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  ```
- Then I made changes in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`,
  removed `BOOTPROTO=dhcp` and made it `BOOTPROTO=none`.
- This is how the old file looks like:

  ```
  [root@network ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 | grep BOOTPROTO
  BOOTPROTO=dhcp
  ```
- Now the new file looks like:

  ```
  [root@network ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 | grep -i BOOTPROTO
  BOOTPROTO=none
  ```
- Reboot the host/VM or start network services.
- This will resolve the issue.